# PowerShell age of file in months

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get information about the files on my drive, like the last time they were accessed. I can get it to return.

```
Get-ChildItem | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM")} | Sort Name | 
    Format-Table Name,Count -auto
```

---

```
Name Count
---- -----
05       2
07       8
10       3
11       2
```

but I'm looking for:

```
Age in Months   Storage Space Used (MB)
0                 100 MB
1                 120 MB
2                 50 MB
3                 20 MB
4                 10 MB
5                 5 MB
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want to group on the number of months between when the file was created and now, not group on the create month? If so then using a `New-Timespan` should do the trick, something like this:

```
ls -File | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Age = [int]((New-TimeSpan -Start $_.LastWriteTime).Days / 31)
        Size = ($_.Length) 
    }
} | Group-Object Age | Select @{
    Name = 'Age in Months'
    Expression = {[int]($_.Name)}}, 
    @{Name ='Storage Size Used (MB)'
    Expression = {[int](($_.Group.Size | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1MB)}
} | sort 'Age in Months'
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you

Comment: I always recommend using full cmdlet names for readability; i.e., replace `ls` with `Get-ChildItem`, `%` with `ForEach-Object`, `Select` with `Select-Object`, and `sort` with `Sort-Object`. (This also avoids problems if someone has redefined an alias.)

Comment: I suppose, I always think it depends on the context and who is the script for. When writing scripts for myself I tend to go the shortest route and be less dogmatic about it, but if it was to run on someone else's system then I would avoid the alias.My rationale for this example was to give emphasis to the `New-Object`, `New-Timespan` and 'Group-Object' and down play the less important elements with respect to the question. However that might be just post-justification on my part.

Comment: Understood - but also keep in mind that people new to PowerShell will benefit from not having to mentally "translate" aliases. In other words - as you say, aliases are fine for personal use, but for public consumption (such as SO), I would say that replacing the aliases is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may achieve what you're going for. Not sure if it's quite the cleanest way but I'm still learning myself.

```
get-childitem | Select-Object Name, @{
    Name = "Age in Months" ;
    e = {[int](((Get-date) - ($_.lastwritetime)).days/30)} 
 } ,

 @{
    Name="Storage Spaced Used (MB)" ;
    e = {[math]::Round($_.Length / 1MB, 2 )}
 } | 



Sort-Object -property "Age in months"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script groups by `yyyy-MM` and uses a [Function Get-FriendlySize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535131/6811411)

```
## https://stackoverflow.com/q/50535131/6811411
function Get-FriendlySize {
    param($Bytes)
    $sizes='Bytes,KB,MB,GB,TB,PB,EB,ZB' -split ','
    for($i=0; ($Bytes -ge 1kb) -and 
        ($i -lt $sizes.Count); $i++) {$Bytes/=1kb}
    $N=2; if($i -eq 0) {$N=0}
    "{0,6:N$($N)} {1}" -f $Bytes, $sizes[$i]
}


Get-ChildItem | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM")}| Sort Name -Desc|ForEach {
   [pscustomobject]@{
       'FileAge' = $_.Name
       'Space Used'= (Get-FriendlySize (($_.Group|measure Length -sum).sum) )
    }
 }
```

Sample output (german locale with decimal comma)

```
FileAge Space Used
------- ----------
2018-05    364 Bytes
2017-08  18,12 KB
2017-07  10,30 KB
2017-06  52,44 KB
2017-05   1,77 KB
2017-04    606 Bytes
2017-03  24,85 KB
2017-02   8,45 KB
2017-01  14,54 KB
2016-12  27,22 KB
2016-11 160,85 KB
2016-10   1,33 MB
2016-09 338,42 KB
2016-08   1,76 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerShellHumanizer](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellHumanizer) module. It adds custom FileSystem Table Format, so you'll see this:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem


    Directory: C:\Program Files\7-Zip


Mode     LastWritten         Length Name
----     -----------         ------ ----
da----   9 months ago               Lang
-a----   one year ago         93 KB 7-zip.chm
-a----   one year ago         79 KB 7-zip.dll
-a----   one year ago         49 KB 7-zip32.dll
-a----   one year ago          1 MB 7z.dll
-a----   one year ago        414 KB 7z.exe
-a----   one year ago        178 KB 7z.sfx
-a----   one year ago        163 KB 7zCon.sfx
-a----   one year ago        784 KB 7zFM.exe
-a----   one year ago        533 KB 7zG.exe
-a----   4 years ago          366 B descript.ion
-a----   one year ago         40 KB History.txt
-a----   one year ago          2 KB License.txt
-a----   one year ago          2 KB readme.txt
```

Comment: That doesn't group / sum up length per month